# FakeItEasy return object that the method is called with

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

I want to setup my fake like this:

```
A.CallTo(() => this.repository.Create(A<PersonModel>._)).Returns(XYZ);
```

where `XYZ` is the same variable as was inserted at `A<PersonModel>._`

so if `Create` is called with `mySamplePersonModel` I want the method to return `mySamplePersonModel`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you found is correct. There's an alternative that is a little more readable IMO:

```
A.CallTo(() => repository.Create(A<PersonModel>._)).ReturnsLazily((PersonModel p) => p);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer you can capture arguments like this:

```
A.CallTo(() => this.repository.Create(A<PersonModel>._)).ReturnsLazily(x => x.Arguments.Get<PersonModel>(0));
```

And you can even modify this parameter like this:

```
A.CallTo(() => this.repository.Create(A<PersonModel>._)).ReturnsLazily(x =>
            {
                var personModel = x.Arguments.Get<PersonModel>(0);
                personModel.Name = "aName";
                return personModel;
            });
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, feel free to post it :-)